# What's the difference between send() and sendAndLoad() in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Quoted from [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001161.html):

```
send(url: String, target: String, [method: String])
```

> Sends the variables in the my_lv
>   object to the specified URL.

```
sendAndLoad(url: String, target: Object, [method: String])
```

> Posts variables in the my_lv object to
>   the specified URL.

I don't see any difference there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sendAndLoad will put received variables (if output from server is like "&a=3&b=9") to object specified as second argument. AFAIK specified object should be type of LoadVars().

For example:

```
var result_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var send_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

send_lv.sendAndLoad(  ...url... , result_lv , "POST");


result_lv.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) 
{
if (success) 
{
... retreive received variables here from result_lv
```

I don't know why i can't put comments.
It's asynchronous, onLoad function will just be called after response from server

...url... it's just url like "http://mydomain.com/myfile.php"